# sed merge 2 lines after a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I want to merge two lines after a pattern using sed (no awk please because I am using windows)
so for example here is the input

```
pattern
XXXXXX
YYYYYY
```

and here is the output:

```
 XXXXXXYYYYYY
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With sed this works:

```
sed -n '/pattern/ {s/.*//; N; N; s/\n//g; p;}'
```

#### Explanation

- `/pattern/` matches pattern and executes the brace block `{ }`.
- `s/.*//` deletes *pattern* from pattern space, a shorter but more obscure way of getting rid of *pattern* is to exchange pattern space and hold space with the `x` command.
- `N` takes next line from input file and appends it to pattern space.
- `s/[\r\n]//g` removes all newlines and carriage returns from pattern space.
- `p` prints pattern space.

A slightly shorter solution for combining 3 lines is:

```
sed -n '/pattern/ {x; N; N; s/\n//g; p;}'
```

Comment: XXXXXX was an example :) , I want to merge the next 2 lines after the pattern

Comment: Then it becomes slightly longer.

Comment: just a quick question ;) , what should I change if I want to merge 3 lines instead of 2 ?

Comment: Just added `\r` to the removal pattern, makes it work with mac and msdos line-endings as well. To get a third line just add a third `N;`.

Comment: The 'N' command appends the next line of the input to the pattern space ([Sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands)). To merge 3 lines use 'N; N; N;' instead of 'N; N;'.

Comment: I use sed a lot, but these detailed sed explanations are still very helpful, more ppl should do that (including me), thx!

Answer (score 1):

Verified on Windows:

```
sed -r '1h; 1!H; ${ g; s/pattern[\r\n]+(.*)[\r\n]+(.*)/\1\2/ p}' infile
```

<sup>Corrected according to [Multiline sed replace](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/27/20-Multi-line-sed-search-and-replace/)</sup>

Comment: Have you verified this? (I believe sed parses the input file line by line.)

Comment: @Vortexfive Not verified, you are right, `sed` parsing line by line by default. I am fixing. Thanks.